# Get module relative path of IFile in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have created an `IFile` instance as follows:

```
IPath filePath = new Path(WebContent/folder1/file1.html);
IFile file = project.getFile(filePath);
```

That file will be deployed on a server and I need to get the module relative path (in this case `/folder1/file1.html`).

I have tried using the `IFlatFile` class like this:

```
IFlatFile flatFile = new FlatFile(file, file.getName(), file.getProjectRelativePath());
IPath modulePath = flatFile.getModuleRelativePath();
```

But the `getModuleRelativePath()` seems to be returning the same path I provided to the constructor when the instance was created.

Is there any other way to get the module relative path of a given file?

Comment: Looking at the source of `FlatFile` `getModuleRelativePath` does just return the path passed to the constructor.

Comment: I guess I can do something like `path = path.removeFirstSegments(1)` but that's definitively not the best approach as it will likely cause problems under certain circumstances

Comment: @CIOC : Can you try: `file.getFullPath().makeRelative()`  and see if it returns what you want?

Comment: I have tried `file.getFullPath().makeRelative()` but it returns the project relative path, i.e: `<project>/WebContent/file.html`